# Object Inizializer in TypeScript

Tags: class, typescript

Is there no equivalent method in TypeScript to inizialize properties like in c#?

```
class ClickEventArgs{
   event: any;
   treeId: any;
   treeNode: any;
   clickFlag: number;
}
```

this seems not to work

```
var args = new ClickEventArgs { event: myEvent };
```

did I do something wrong with the syntax or is this not supported in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> did I do something wrong with the syntax or is this not supported in TypeScript?

It isn't supported.

You can use other libraries e.g. `underscore` to do it though

e.g.

```
var args = new ClickEventArgs();
args = _.extend(args, { event: myEvent });
```